# Is there any event before $locationChangeStart?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I want to re-init a service variable before every page loaded.
It seems $locationChange cannot match this needs in some condition

```
angular.module('xxx')
...
.service('xxxsvc', [..., function(){
    var groups = {};
}

$rootScope.on('$locationChange', function(){
    groups = {}
});
}]);
```

I used serveral directive on the page use this service, it seems $locationChange isn't executed before all directives. I want to re-init or clear the variable before any part of page is initialized.

Does anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is `stateChangeStart` and since you can even cancel it during the operation, nothing else should happen before it. But I see that you use `'$locationChange'` and not `'$stateChangeStart'`, maybe that is the issue?

You can read about `$stateChangeStart` [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

Another possible problem, did you verify that your service is called at all? The controller initialize is usually not called again unless you force it.